# Skip git-code-format-maven-plugin from cosium during mvn install

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, code-formatting

I have a project that is using git-code-format-maven-plugin from com.cosium.code to format code as a pre-commit hook. I am setting up a build pipeline to install this project and the runner machines do not have git installed.

So the plugin is throwing exception

> Failed to execute goal com.cosium.code:git-code-format-maven-plugin:3.1:install-hooks (default) on project chat-srv: One of setGitDir or setWorkTree must be called. -> [Help 1]

Command I am executing is `mvn -f /app/pom.xml clean install`

Is it possible to skip the code foramtting during the mvn install and enable it only for git commits? Or isit possible to skip using the plugin during the pipeline builds?

**pom.xml**

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.cosium.code</groupId>
            <artifactId>git-code-format-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-hooks</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <googleJavaFormatOptions>
                    <aosp>true</aosp>
                </googleJavaFormatOptions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip a plugin by using the attribute {}. Use a property and set it to true when you are building.

```
<properties>
        <skipFormatCode>false</skipFormatCode>
    </properties>    
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.cosium.code</groupId>
            <artifactId>git-code-format-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-hooks</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <skip>${skipFormatCode}</skip>
                <googleJavaFormatOptions>
                    <aosp>true</aosp>
                </googleJavaFormatOptions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

When you want to skip the plugin run using

> mvn clean install -DskipFormatCode=true